# setVerboseLoggingEnabled not showing log of tag manager

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

below code in `google play service 7.0` showing perfect logs.

```
tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(activity);
tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
```

but, its not working in version `8.1` and `8.4`.
so, is it something like its not backword compatible or any other issue?

please, help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue with the GTM sdk from the google play services v7+. It wont show any logs even though you have enabled the verbose logging.

As Google Tag Manager SDK is only showing the logs for the hits being sent to the Google Analytics, you can check the logs that is being sent to Google Analytics using below command:

```
$ adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
```

Just fire this command on terminal & it will create a logcat filter with **GAv4** & enables the Google Analytics Logs. You can create a filter in logcat with "GAv4" then all the logs will be shown.

Let me know if you need more information on this.

Regards,
V